# 'DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Columns'

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I get the following error trying to add columns to datatable

> *DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Columns' and no extension method 'Columns' accepting a first argument of type
>   'DataTable' could be found*

Here is the code that generated the error!

```
static void Main()
{
    // Get the DataTable
    DataTable myTable = getStatusTable();
}

static DataTable getStatusTable()
{
    // Create a DataTable with 4 columns       
    DataTable myTable = new DataTable();   

    myTable.Columns.Add("Dosage");
    myTable.Columns.Add("Drug");
    myTable.Columns.Add("Patient");
    myTable.Columns.Add("Date");

    // Create the Table Row
    myTable.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
    myTable.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
    myTable.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
    myTable.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
    myTable.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
    myTable.Rows.Add(25, "Vitamin C", "Guzzyman", DateTime.Now);

    return myTable;
}
```

How can I rectify this issue?

Comment: did you add `using System.Data;`?

Comment: having a custom DataTable class ?

Comment: I just tried this exact code in a console app and it worked fine, could you share your stack trace?

Comment: @Steve, there could be another `DataTable` class in scope, and adding the `using` clause would result in a conflict that would make clear if it is the case.

Comment: @Steve I know but sometime it happen

Comment: There's no other datatable in scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created a custom `DataTable` class somewhere. This class is in a namespace that's in the `using` list. You need to fully qualify it like this:

```
System.Data.DataTable myTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
```

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, I think it's less a guess than an observation. If the `class` is being recognized but a well known member of the expected class isn't, there is a custom `DataTable` class somewhere in the list of available namespaces. It may even be in the same namespace as this class I suppose.

Comment: I also tried using System.Data.DataTable but git this error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'DataTable' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: @Guzzyman, that's because **everywhere you reference `DataTable`** needs to be fully qualified. You have a *return type* of `DataTable` and you're setting a new reference of a `DataTable` with the *return value.* You need to **fully qualify all of them.**

Comment: @Guzzyman, check if you accidentally created a class named DataTable in your own code, and delete it if you don't need it. It can happen if you inadvertently used the "create class from usage" feature.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THE BELOW CODE

```
myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Dosage"));
myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Drug"));
myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Patient"));
myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date"));
```

Comment: this will generate same error because you just use another version of `Add` method of undefined collection.

Comment: Yes...I added using System.Data